# Why can't we debug a method with yield return for the following code?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

Following is my code:

```
class Program {
    static List<int> MyList;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyList = new List<int>() { 1,24,56,7};
        var sn = FilterWithYield();
    }
    static IEnumerable<int> FilterWithYield() {
        foreach (int i in MyList) {
            if (i > 3)
                yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a break point in `FilterWithYield` Method but its not at all hitting the break point. I have one break at the calling point i.e  `var sn = FilterWithYield();` Control hits this point and shows the result correctly in debugging window. But why isn't the control stopping in the FilterWithYield method?

One more question. I read that yield returns data to the caller..if that is so if changed return type of FilterWithYield  method to int it through error.Does the yield key word always need `IEnumerable<T>` as return type?

Comment: @Rob, not true, as well as `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, it can also return an `IEnumerator<T>` or `IEnumerator` which can be useful in some cases, most often as a convenient way to implement `GetEnumerator()` when you're implementing the rest of an enumerable another way, though there are some other times it's useful.

Comment: There are other duplicates (search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+yield+breakpoint) including one with links to the Eric Lippert blog posts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024080/cant-step-into-iterator-block-whilst-debugging-c.

Comment: @JonHanna You're absolutely right, I did not know it could actually return an enumerator.

Comment: @Rob it doesn't come up as often, but it can certainly be useful at times.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can debug the method. The problem is, the code that you are trying to reach is never executed.

`IEnumerable` methods with `yield return` produce code that makes your sequence lazily, as you go through enumeration. However, when you do this

```
var sn = FilterWithYield();
```

you prepare to enumerate the sequence, but you do not start enumerating it.

If, on the other hand, you add a `foreach` loop or call `ToList()` on the result, your breakpoint would get hit:

```
foreach (var n in FilterWithYield()) {
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

or

```
var sn = FilterWithYield().ToList();
```