# Breakpoints wont be hit in certain function

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

Im using VS2015 linked to a unity3d project and breakpoints will not be hit in one particular function.
breakpoints work fine in every other function in that file. I have cleaned > rebuilt solution, restarted the computer and loaded the .pdb files manually. How to fix this?
See image
[broken function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaeFl.png)

[image]

Comment: Where is the method called?  Can you post the code?

Comment: It is being called in the function directly above it with unity's StartCoroutine(). Image http://i.imgsafe.org/f706f82ae5.png

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we debug a method with yield return for the following code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446723/why-cant-we-debug-a-method-with-yield-return-for-the-following-code)

Comment: Also, as a side note, code belongs in your question and not as an image. Stack Overflow is intended to be a resource for everyone to use. If your image link expires, then this question will be useless as nobody can tell what the code causing the issue was.

Comment: could it be that line 581 `if` statement isn't true ?