# Initialisation of Enumerators

Tags: c#, enumerator

So I'm slowly reading my way through a work book and have come to the section on enumerators. During which it gives the example code of

```
public class GameMoves
{
    private IEnumerator _cross;
    private IEnumerator _circle;

    private int i;

    public GameMoves()
    {            
        _cross = Cross();
        _circle = Circle();
        i = I();
    }
    private int _move = 0;
    const int MaxMoves = 9;

    public int I()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        return (1);
    }

    public IEnumerator Cross()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            WriteLine($"Cross, move {_move}");
            if (++_move >= MaxMoves)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return _circle;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Circle()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            WriteLine($"Circle, move {_move}");
            if (++_move >= MaxMoves)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return _cross;
        }
    }
}
```

I run this from the main method and create a new instance of this class. When the constructor runs `_cross = Cross();` I expected it to work similarly to `i = I();` i.e. run through the class and take the returned value. When I step through the program, it doesn't seem to activate the `Cross()` class at all, instead that line creates an enumerator with the value of null. Just wondering if someone could explain what that step is doing. Thanks

Comment: you mean "i.e run through the method.. " ?

Comment: Your terminology is off. Your talking about "iterators", not "enumerators". Also, both `I` and `Cross` are methods, not classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we debug a method with yield return for the following code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446723/why-cant-we-debug-a-method-with-yield-return-for-the-following-code)

Comment: Have a look at [C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) which goes into all the things the compiler does behind the scenes for you - it's really not as simple as it looks on the surface. All you're doing when you call the method is getting a new copy of the IEnumerator state machine

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of iterators is exactly what you're seeing. An iterator is supposed to defer execution until the results are actually used. In your code, the `I` method is not an iterator so its body is executed to completion when you call it. The `Cross` method is an iterator so its body doesn't get executed until you use the result.

For instance, if you were to use a `foreach` loop to enumerate `_cross` you would see that each iteration of the loop would cause a `yield` keyword to be hit inside the `Cross` method.  Once the `yield break` is hit, the method has completed and your loop would exit.

As an example of why this is good, let's compare the `File.ReadAllLines` method and the `File.ReadLines` method. The former has been around since .NET 1.0 while the latter is a much later addition.  The `ReadAllLines` method reads the entire file and breaks it up into lines, then returns an array containing those lines.  That means that you cannot start processing the file until its entire contents has been read.  It also means that you must read the entire contents even if you don't need it.  For instance, if there were a million lines and you wanted the first one containing a particular word, you'd have to read every line even if you found the word in the tenth line.

By contrast, the `ReadLines` method is an iterator.  It doesn't start reading the file until you actually need the data and it only reads the data as it's needed.  That means that you can process the data as it's read rather than waiting until it's all been read to start processing.  It also means that you don't have to read any more data than is required, e.g. if you start looking for a word and find it on the tenth line, the remaining 999,990 lines will not be read.