# My unit test cannot cover yield return function

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This is the class to test:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetInt()
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        yield return 4;
        yield return 5;
    }
}
```

My simple unit test:

```
[Test]
public void TestYieldReturn()
{
    var test = new TestClass();
    var results = test.GetInt();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Min());
    Assert.AreEqual(5, results.Max());
}
```

My test didn't cover this implementation, I ran it in debug mode but it didn't hit the breakpoint. Any suggestion?

Comment: What test framework are you using? I also wonder if the compiler is smart enough to optimise the `yield` statements away..

Comment: Should `results` be named `testresult` in your example, or is there something else that's been omitted that defines `testresult`?

Comment: "I ran it in debug mode but it didn't hit the breakpoint" - what breakpoint?

Comment: I found the solution, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446723/why-cant-we-debug-a-method-with-yield-return-for-the-following-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply must materialize the list first because `yield` returns and enumerable, not an actual list.

```cs
var results = test.GetInt().ToList();
```

Comment: Min/Max works on an IEnumerable<T>. No need for a ToList();

Comment: And `Min`/`Max` have to get to the end of the sequence in order to return, so it really should exercise *all* the `yield` statements.